# Index specific TypeORM entity fields

Tags: reflection, nestjs, typeorm

I'm building an indexing service to index various entity fields. I'd like to be able to add a decorator like `@Searchable` or similar to the fields I want to decorate and then using some kind of indexing service (and probably reflection) find all the entity classes (those with the `@Entity` decorator), then in each one of those, gather up all of the fields with `@Searchable` decorators applied to them.

The issue is - I'm running into issues trying to use reflection to find the entities an it's starting to feel like I'm approaching the issue wrong.

I've tried putting the smarts in the decorator and having it register with some kind of external service every time it's called, but this feels very fragile and requires a singleton of that service to be available to "hold" the data.

Comment: Hello! Why do you need to index fields?

Comment: @ByMsx to build an index table in my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the (partial) solution ended up being the following code:

```js
// Turn entities with decorated field into SELECT queries
const data = this.ds.entityMetadatas
// Returns only the models that have at least one decorated column
.filter(({ isJunction, target, columns }) => {
  if (isJunction) return false;
  return columns.some(
    ({ propertyName }) => Reflect
      .hasOwnMetadata(SEARCHABLE_DECORATOR_KEY, target, propertyName)
  );
})
.map(({ target, tableName, columns, primaryColumns }) => {
  const query = this.ds.createQueryBuilder()
    .from(tableName, tableName.charAt(0));
  columns.filter(({ propertyName, isPrimary }) =>
    // Returns only the columns that are
    // 1) Decorated and
    // 2) not primary columns (that way we're not
    // indexing primary key columns)
    Reflect.hasOwnMetadata(SEARCHABLE_DECORATOR_KEY, target, propertyName)
    && !isPrimary,
  ).concat(primaryColumns)
   // Uses the query builder to turn those columns into a SELECT query
  .forEach(({ propertyName }) => query.addSelect(`"${propertyName}"`))
  return query;
});
```

This returns an (unexecuted) query per table that selects only the decorated columns. So for the following entity:

```js
@Entity()
class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Searchable
  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;
}
```

it would generate the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT id, name FROM "user";
```

Note that `id` is still selected because we need that later in order to associate the key/value with the PK value (that way we can retrieve records by PK, which is kinda the point of this after all, right?)

I also have my `@Searchable` decorator - the code for which looks like this:

```js
export const SEARCHABLE_DECORATOR_KEY = Symbol('searchable');

/**
 * Searchable decorator used to make an entity property visible to the search
 * spider
 */
export const Searchable = (target:Object, property: string) => {
  Reflect
    .defineMetadata(SEARCHABLE_DECORATOR_KEY, true, target.constructor, property);
}
```

Note the `target.constructor` there. For reasons I don't fully understand, if you use `target` instead of `target.constructor` - it returns the entity parent class (if there is one) instead of the actual entity you're decorating. So if you have:

```js
class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Searchable
  @Column()
  id: string;
}
```

then `target` would equal `BaseEntity` while `target.entity` gives `class User extends BaseEntity` which is what we want here.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, that it doesn't work, because TypeORM `@Entity` decorator doesn't set class metadata ([source](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/decorator/entity/Entity.ts#L33)). So you could use your own decorator to mark entity classes and find them. Also you may need `@Injectable` to make nestjs register your classes.

There is an example of finding classes with metadata: ([sources on github](https://github.com/grammyjs/nestjs/blob/main/packages/grammy-nestjs/src/services/listeners-explorer.service.ts#L54)).

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks. I've managed to achieve _some_ success my decorating the properties I want to decorate and getting the class that way. I then run into the issue of how to persist that info though because decorators don't have access to the Nest DI container so I can't inject anything...

I have thought of importing some kind of global import and having that hold the data until I can write it to a database.

Comment: @robertmain , may be you could to change your approach? Do not use decorators to manage something except decorated target. I suggest you create a new service, which will explore all entities and will find decorated properties. After, you can call that service in `onApplicationBootstrap` or in `onModuleInit`. So you don't need to inject something to decorator and you don't need to store anything about that properties before exploring.

Comment: I did try this approach initially, but that still leaves me needing to somehow search the application container though and it's hard to do this without a good way to tell what's an entity and what isn't.

I also still want to have decorators in some form so I can choose which fields to pay attention to and which to ignore.

Comment: @robertmain , I can't understand problem in first approach. Can you post your code for 1st approach?

Comment: I figured it out! I had to do some reflection witchcraft, but I figured it out!